# How can I use Tika to parse PDF without having Java on my PC(In Python)

Tags: java, python, apache-tika, temp, tika-server

We need to have Java 8 or higher for Tika to work in python. It creates a server.jar in the temp folder. I was thinking if we can add it in a folder where my python file is kept so the user doesn't need to have Java installed

Comment: Apache Tika is written in Java, so you need the JVM installed to run it, no way around that

Comment: @Gagravarr correct but what if i make a setup compliler and install open jdk. Ig it should work. I tried that but it still shows same error. Do I have to change path or env variables or what?????